# Embedding a martingale by SDE

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Let me reformulate my question. Let $(X_0,X_T)$ be a martingale on $\mathbb R$, then it is known that one has a SDE:

$$Z_t=Z_0+\int_0^t\sigma(s,Z_s)dB_s, \mbox{ for all } t\in [0,T]~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(\ast)$$

s.t. $Z_0\sim X_0$ and $Z_T\sim X_T$. My question is the following: **Could we construct a similar SDE above s.t.**

$$(Z_0,Z_T)~~\sim~~(X_0,X_T)?$$

PS: Some references: https://www.maths.univ-evry.fr/prepubli/334.pdf

Comment: What are the quantifiers on $\gamma, \mu,$ and $\nu$?

Comment: $Z_0,Z_T$ should form a martingale, so not in all case, as e.g. when the variance of $Z_T$ is smaller.

Comment: @michael That's implied by the definition of $\gamma$. Indeed, for any pair $(\mu,\nu)$ satisfying the above condition, one always has a martingale with the marginals $\mu$ and $\nu$. See the paper https://www.maths.univ-evry.fr/prepubli/334.pdf

Comment: @PatDevlin Actually. We may understand the problem in another way: Given a martingale $(X_0,X_T)$ with marginal laws $\mu$ and $\nu$, could we embed this martingale to a solution $(Z_t)_{0\le t\le T}$ given by the SDE, i.e. $(X_0,X_T)\sim (Z_0,Z_T)$?